# AngularJS $http callback not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.submitNewUser = function() { 
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'api/user/signup',
                data: {'user': $scope.user},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},                 
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('hello');
                alert('boo');
            });
        }
```

I have the above and when its ran the POST works but I'm unable to get the `.success()` part to work, there is no callback and the `console.log()` and `alert()` do not fire.

Thanks

Comment: Have you any error in console? Also sharing your complete controller code can help us to answer you.

Comment: And have you tried to use fiddler? Do you get any response?

Comment: try to add `.error` callback after `.success` and make console.log of function parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the error handler

```
      console.log("calling http;")
      $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/user/signup',
            data: {'user': $scope.user},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},                 
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success', data, status);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error', data, status);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log('catch', error);
        });
```

Comment: There is no response other than the echo json return from the `api/user/signup` itself.

Comment: what do you get if you do `console.log(status);console.log(data);`,

Comment: Nothing gets triggered. FF console.log only shows that the post has been sent and shows the echo content from inside the `user` request, the javascript callback is not firing or showing up. Perhaps my initial angular is wrong?